# Unexpected token at every .js file at line 2

Tags: javascript, django, console

I'm getting syntax error at every js file i have linked to my page. 
The page is working fine when I set DEBUG = TRUE but this error occurs when I set it to False.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

when click to see where at line 2 the error is it takes me to  tag of my 404 page.

Comment: Seems like your server is returning HTML (the 404 page), not JS. Make sure your JS files are accessible / the routing configuration of your server is correct.

Comment: It is very likely that those requests for static files are returning a 404 page, thank the actual asset files. Check the path and try again

Comment: Possibly debug = false gives `*.min.js` that aren't actually there?

Comment: @karthikr, on my terminal I am getting HTTP 200 OK response for all the CSS, JS and jpeg files. but they are not getting load on the page. 
When I click the link from the page source my bootstrap.min.css is loaded and other css and js files gives 404 error. 
all the files were collected in the static root by collectstatic command but I am not able to figure out what is causing the trouble that some files are getting served and some are not.

Comment: Is this using nginx/apache or something? If so, check the settings there. Make sure it points to the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

When settings DEBUG = False, your static files have to be deployed to be served.

You can find here some information about how deploying your static files : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/